# Custom tag files in jee6 and jee7

Tags: java, legacy

I am working on migration of a legacy web applications and having issues with the compilation of custom tag files.

We have a number of **.tag** files which are under */WEB-INF/tags* folder and are being referenced in other jsp files using `<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tag" %>`

Current tech stack: Java 7, JEE5 and Weblogic 10.3,
Target tech stack: Java 8, JEE7 and Weblogic 12.2.1.3

It looks like JEE7 (or even JEE6) no longer support custom tag files. Can someone help guide how to migrate all these tag files to target tech stack by removing compilation errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official JEE 7 tutorial, which can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/JEETT.pdf JEE 7 supports JSP 2.3.

> For information about JSP technology, see the The Java EE 5 Tutorial at
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/.
>   The Java EE 7 platform requires JavaServer Pages 2.3 for compatibility with earlier
>   releases but recommends the use of Facelets as the display technology in new
>   applications.

The JSP 2.3 Spec includes tag libraries, so a compliant JEE7 server must support JSP custom tags. If you encounter any specific error, please follow the instructions [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

The recommended file extension for a tag file is .tag. See [Encapsulating Reusable Content Using Tag Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html).